# populating a Combobox in class library error :'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' works in WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, class

populating a Combobox in class library

I have a WPF project with Controls on it,

I want to access WPF Controls within my class library and im getting the error

```
The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 
'System.Windows' 

(are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

The problem does not happen when accessing the functions from WPF project it only becomes a problem when i try and do something with them from the class library

Comment: Well have you added the Ref to the library ?

Comment: `are you missing an assembly reference?` is the best error message hint I've ever seen.  Too bad they put it in parentheses.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As the message suggests, you are probably missing an assembly reference.  Make sure your class library includes a reference to the .NET `PresentationFramework` assembly and you should be fine.

Comment: awesome that does the trick, adding using System.Windows.Control broke !!! excellent many thanks !